# Data offline persistence with Contentful in Android

Tags: contentful, contentful-management, contentful-api, contentful-vault

Have anyone recently done offline data persistence with Contentful in Android app developed using Kotlin ?  The Contentful  official documentation and the linked sample projects seems no update for the past few years. Facing issues in integration.

[Contentful Vault](https://github.com/contentful/vault)

[Contentful Vault Documentation](https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/android/tutorials/offline-persistence-with-vault/)

[Sample app using Vault](https://github.com/contentful-labs/droidstory)

Comment: Can you phrase the issues? Without knowing issues it's hard to give advise.

Comment: Getting error like "Duplicate class com.contentful.java.cda.AbsQuery found in modules jetified-contentful.java-v10.4.1 (com.github.contentful:contentful.java:v10.4.1) and jetified-java-sdk-10.1.0 (com.contentful.java:java-sdk:10.1.0)
Du". And more error similar to this. Would help if can point any updated document to follow.